# Exponential Approximation of the Modified Bessel Function of first kind (Equation)

Tags: reference-request, functions

Hello Dear Sir/Madam,

Could someone please tell me the reference or equation for "Exponential Approximation of the Modified Bessel Function of first kind" or any matlab function to compute it. My problem is I am getting NaN and Inf value from modified bessel function of first kind with order 0 and 1 so I want to approximate bessel functions by exponentials.Thank you in advance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind_:_J.CE.B1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both $I_0(x)$ and $I_1(x)$ are [approximately](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40)

$$\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2 \pi x}}$$

for sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much but my x is large enough range from 255 to 3500.Basically i will use I_0(x) and I_1(x) first for my data then if there occurs NaN ans Inf value i want to approximate it with Exponential Approximation, so if i approximate it with \frac{e^x}{sqrt{2\pi x}} it should be fine right ?

Comment: Frequently, you are interested in the quantity $e^{-x} I_0(x)$. When you use the exponential approximation, you merely end up computing $1/\sqrt{2 \pi x}$, which is no trouble.

Comment: Failing that, you can compute the log of $I_0(x)$ as approximately $x - \frac12 \log{2 \pi x}$.

Comment: Thank you so much Ron i truly appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome.  If what I said was useful, please remember to accept the solution by clicking the checkmark under the upvote number.

Answer (score 3):

The Asymptotic Approximation of Modified Bessel Functions for Large Values of x:

[image]

Comment: Can you please give a reference?

Comment: Looks like it's from http://mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap4.pdf